# How to Reveal in Project Navigator automatically

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to reveal the currently edited file in the project navigator in xcode

I know about the right-click and Reveal in Project Navigator

[How to highlight opened file in XCode 4 on the "Project Navigator" panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133225/how-to-highlight-opened-file-in-xcode-4-on-the-project-navigator-panel)

But it's a manual task

I want it to show EVERY TIME I switch files - like the 2 yellow arrows on top of the Eclipse IDE

I want the project navigator to always highlight the currently edited file.

Thanks,
Nur

Comment: That is a real wish from me too, do you have an open feature request at apple?

Comment: Sadly it didn't change in Xcode 5. I searched in the preferences but didn't find any feature that could toggle this behavior. Maybe there is an option I have overseen?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Hum... I don't have the answer of your question and I really would like to know it.

But I know something better than right clicking, that is called : <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>

Your hands are on the keyboard, at least you won't have to get the mouse...

Answer (score 6):

At the bottom of project navigator panel "Show only recent file" filter option is given select it to view only recent files edited

Comment: Better than nothing. But if I hop between only some classes that wouldn't help ;(.